# x64 hook Fails on Messagebox

Tags: c++, function-hooking

Quite new to the intels so i might not know much , I just need some form of direction here.
I am trying to do a simple 64 bit hook detour for function hooking

I do it like so :

The detour hook Engine :

```
BOOL JHook::SetHook(LPCSTR dll, LPCSTR name, LPVOID proxy, LPVOID original, PDWORD length)
{
    LPVOID FunctionAddress;
    DWORD TrampolineLength = 0, OriginalProtection;
    hde64s disam;
    BYTE Jump[13] = { 0x49, 0xBB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0xFF, 0xE3 };

    FunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(dll), name);
    if (!FunctionAddress)
        return FALSE;

    //disassemble length of each instruction, until we have 5 or more bytes worth
    while (TrampolineLength < 5)
    {
        LPVOID InstPointer = (LPVOID)((DWORD)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength);
        TrampolineLength += hde64_disasm(InstPointer, &disam);
    }

    //Build the trampoline buffer
    memcpy(original, FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);
    *(DWORD*)(Jump + 1) = ((DWORD)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength) - ((DWORD)original + TrampolineLength + 5);
    memcpy((LPVOID)((DWORD)original + TrampolineLength), Jump, 5);

    //Make sure the function is writable
    if (!VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OriginalProtection))
        return FALSE;

    //Build and atomically write the hook
    *(DWORD*)(Jump + 1) = (DWORD)proxy - (DWORD)FunctionAddress - 5;
    //SafeMemcpyPadded(FunctionAddress, Jump, 5);

    //Restore the original page protection
    VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, OriginalProtection, &OriginalProtection);

    //Clear CPU instruction cache
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);

    *length = TrampolineLength;
    return TRUE;
}
```

The header file.

```
#pragma once

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include "hde64.h"

    class SHook
    {
    private :
        LPVOID FunctionAddress;
        DWORD TrampolineLength = 0, OriginalProtection;
        hde64s disam;
        BYTE Jump[13] = { 0x49, 0xBB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0xFF, 0xE3 };
    public:
        BOOL SetHook(LPCSTR dll, LPCSTR name, LPVOID proxy, LPVOID original, PDWORD length);
    };
```

Now the implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <string>
#include "JHook.h"

typedef int (WINAPI* TdefOldMessageBoxA)(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
TdefOldMessageBoxA myOldMessageBoxA;

JHook Jhook;
int WINAPI HookMessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType) 
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hooked", "Hooked", MB_OK);
    return myOldMessageBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

void EstablishHook()
{
        Jhook.SetHook("user32.dll","MessageBoxA", (LPVOID)&HookMessageBoxA, myOldMessageBoxA,0);
}

int main() 
{
    EstablishHook();
}
```

Now i was expecting to see something like a Messagebox saying its hooked, and i just see a cmd nothing else, where am i getting it wrong?

**Edit**

Opening inside a Debugger i have this

```
00007FF663D143F4 | 55                       | push rbp                                |
00007FF663D143F5 | 57                       | push rdi                                |
00007FF663D143F6 | 48:81EC E8000000         | sub rsp,E8                              |
00007FF663D143FD | 48:8D6C24 20             | lea rbp,qword ptr ss:[rsp+20]           |
00007FF663D14402 | 48:8BFC                  | mov rdi,rsp                             |
00007FF663D14405 | B9 3A000000              | mov ecx,3A                              | 3A:':'
00007FF663D1440A | B8 CCCCCCCC              | mov eax,CCCCCCCC                        |
00007FF663D1440F | F3:AB                    | rep stosd                               |
00007FF663D14411 | 48:8B8C24 08010000       | mov rcx,qword ptr ss:[rsp+108]          |
00007FF663D14419 | 48:8D0D 15FC0000         | lea rcx,qword ptr ds:[7FF663D24035]     | MessageBoxTest.cpp:15732480
00007FF663D14420 | E8 5DCCFFFF              | call shook.7FF663D11082                 |
00007FF663D14425 | 45:33C9                  | xor r9d,r9d                             | MessageBoxTest.cpp:13
00007FF663D14428 | 4C:8D05 95880000         | lea r8,qword ptr ds:[7FF663D1CCC4]      | 00007FF663D1CCC4:"Hooked"
00007FF663D1442F | 48:8D15 8E880000         | lea rdx,qword ptr ds:[7FF663D1CCC4]     | 00007FF663D1CCC4:"Hooked"
00007FF663D14436 | 33C9                     | xor ecx,ecx                             |
00007FF663D14438 | FF15 2AED0000            | call qword ptr ds:[<&MessageBoxA>]      |
00007FF663D1443E | 44:8B8D F8000000         | mov r9d,dword ptr ss:[rbp+F8]           | MessageBoxTest.cpp:14
00007FF663D14445 | 4C:8B85 F0000000         | mov r8,qword ptr ss:[rbp+F0]            |
00007FF663D1444C | 48:8B95 E8000000         | mov rdx,qword ptr ss:[rbp+E8]           |
00007FF663D14453 | 48:8B8D E0000000         | mov rcx,qword ptr ss:[rbp+E0]           |
00007FF663D1445A | FF15 90AF0000            | call qword ptr ds:[<int (__cdecl* __ptr |
00007FF663D14460 | 48:8DA5 C8000000         | lea rsp,qword ptr ss:[rbp+C8]           | MessageBoxTest.cpp:15
00007FF663D14467 | 5F                       | pop rdi                                 |
00007FF663D14468 | 5D                       | pop rbp                                 |
00007FF663D14469 | C3                       | ret                                     |
```

Which shows the MessageBox Now i am a bit lost as to what to do next. Worked on detour Function, pls see above.

**Edit**

NOW i fixed the Sethook Engine now and it looks like this somehow

```
#include "SHook.h"

BOOL SHook::SetHook(LPCSTR dll, LPCSTR name, LPVOID proxy, LPVOID original, PDWORD length)
{
    LPVOID FunctionAddress;
    DWORD TrampolineLength = 0, OriginalProtection;
    hde64s disam;
    BYTE Jump[14] = { 0xFF, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    FunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(dll), name);
    if (!FunctionAddress)
        return FALSE;

    //disassemble length of each instruction, until we have 5 or more bytes worth
    while (TrampolineLength < 5)
    {
        LPVOID InstPointer = (LPVOID)((DWORD64)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength);
        TrampolineLength += hde64_disasm(InstPointer, &disam);
    }

    //Build the trampoline buffer
    memcpy(original, FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);
    *(DWORD64*)(Jump + 1) = ((DWORD64)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength) - ((DWORD64)original + TrampolineLength + 5); // <-- error falls here
    memcpy((LPVOID)((DWORD64)original + TrampolineLength), Jump, 5);

    //Make sure the function is writable
    if (!VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OriginalProtection))
        return FALSE;

    //Build and atomically write the hook
    *(DWORD64*)(Jump + 1) = (DWORD64)proxy - (DWORD64)FunctionAddress - 5;
    //SafeMemcpyPadded(FunctionAddress, Jump, 5);

    //Restore the original page protection
    VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, OriginalProtection, &OriginalProtection);

    //Clear CPU instruction cache
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);

    *length = TrampolineLength;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Other things remain the same. do not have an idea why it fails still , especially on this line :

```
*(DWORD64*)(Jump + 1) = ((DWORD64)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength) - ((DWORD64)original + TrampolineLength + 5);
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `MessageBoxA` in order to trigger the hook.

Comment: How u mean sir? @0xec

Comment: I meant in the code you posted there's no call to `MessageBoxA` after setting the hook in order to check if it works or not.

Comment: @0xec now i get this as error : Exception thrown: read access violation.
p was 0x82042490.

Comment: Now you need to use a debugger (x64dbg) and trace through the code particularly where you are calling `MessageBoxA`

Comment: @0xec , Please see Edits. Now i managed to open the function inside the debugger as you said, I have that. So Pls i need some more explanation as to why it crashed.

Comment: Navigate (Ctrl +g) to `MessageBoxA` in x64dbg after you set the hook. If the hook was successful you should see `jmp` instruction to the trampoline.

Comment: no it wasnt , i fixed some part of the code along the line and it fires a new error this time. Pls see edits.